# MySQL-выборка по двум параметрам

Tags: mysql

MySQL не мой конёк, поэтому даже не знал, как правильно написать заголовок поста... В общем, дело в следующем.
К примеру, есть одна таблица **table** с двумя полями **F1** и **F2**

[image]

Ищем в поле **F2**, получаем **DISTINCT F1**. Если параметр один, к примеру **А**, то на выходе получаем три записи: **7**, **12**, **5**. Но вот если будет два параметра **А** и **В**, то как сделать запрос, чтобы вытащить только две записи **7** и **5**. Отсеиваем **12** , т.к. у него параметр **В** не встречается? Так, как строю запрос я - этого естественно достичь нельзя.

```
SELECT DISTINCT F1 FROM table WHERE F2 IN ('A','B')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.F1
FROM `table` t1
  JOIN (SELECT tt2.F1 FROM `table` tt2 WHERE tt2.F2='B') t2 ON t1.F1 = t2.F1
WHERE t1.F2='A';
```

Comment: Ох, спасибо. Избавили меня от бессонной ночи ))

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю необходимо получить значения f1 у которых есть все значения f2(A, B, C), запрос будет такого вида:

```
SELECT DISCTINCT f1, f2, count(*) as cnt from tbl group by f1, f2 having cnt = 3;
```

Comment: Спасибо. Очень близко, но немного не так работает. В общем-то, @Yura Ivanov дал полностью удовлетворяющее решение.